# Should I approve an edit for an old question?

Tags: discussion, editing

When reviewing suggested edits I came across [this edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/272610). I noticed that this edit was for a question from 2011. I was unsure whether I should approve this edit, which was just to add some relevant tags. I see that the edit should be approved because it's an edit that follow the edit guidelines, and yet I didn't want to approve a question from 2011 which already had a correct answer, because it would [bump it to the homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114034/does-editing-still-bump-a-question)

My question is whether or not I should approve edits to old questions, answered or unanswered.

Comment: Related: [When should we edit old questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7472/28182) and [What is the point of editing year old questions to remove tags?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7966/28182)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Especially since this case is a retag, I would say **yes**. We don't want content with errors, and mistagged content is even worse in my view. Ultimately, use your best judgement, but it isn't that big of a deal for things to get bumped, as long as we aren't bumping a whole bunch of things at the same time during, for example, a mass cleanup effort.

Comment: Thanks! I left this unaccepted for a while to see other peoples inputs (if any), but seeing as there was none I'll use your answer for future reference.

Comment: I wouldn't mind a mass cleanup effort bumping content, either. You can always sort by newest or by tag if you want to see something specific.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud Typically, we don't want a cleanup effort to take up the entire front page though. It's usually fine to grab things a few at a time and let the front page work itself out over a few days

Comment: The fact that I have less that 2K rep and can only submit 5 edits at a time solves the front-page-flooding problem for itself.